# Javascript optimization for custom contentEditable div implementation

Tags: javascript, optimization, innerhtml

I have a div that is **not** contentEditable. I listen for keypress events, maintain a string in memory, and on a set interval I iterate over the string and blast the contents into the innerHTML of the div. I have to iterate over the string, rather than simply replacing the innerHTML of the div with the string as a whole because I can't keep html tags in memory for reasons specific to my application. Thus, I iterate over the string, and replace linebreaks with br tags, etc. Everything works fine, except once a decent amount of text is in the div, the application slows to a crawl because of having to iterate over each character individually. See the algorithm below for what I'm currently doing:

```
for (var i=0, len=this.value.string.length; i<len; i++) {
  var p = this.value.string[i];
  if(p['char']==this.newLine){
    if(i<start){
      a.push('<br>');
    }else if(i>end){
      c.push('<br>');
    }else{
      b.push('<br>');
    }
  }else if(p['char']==this.newSpace){
    if(i<start){
      a.push('<span>&nbsp; </span>');
    }else if(i>=end){
      c.push('<span>&nbsp; </span>');
    }else{
      b.push('<span>&nbsp; </span>');
    }
  }else{
    if(i<start){
      a.push('<span>'+p['char']+'</span>');
    }else if(i>=end){
      c.push('<span>'+p['char']+'</span>');
    }else{
      b.push('<span>'+p['char']+'</span>');
    }
  }
}

var tempA = a.join("");
var tempB = b.join("");
var tempC = c.join("");

dojo.byId('thisFrame').innerHTML = tempA;
dojo.create('span',{
        id:'selection',
        innerHTML:tempB,
        'class':'selection'
    },
    dojo.byId('thisFrame'),
    'last'
);
dojo.byId('thisFrame').innerHTML = dojo.byId('thisFrame').innerHTML + tempC;
```

To explain a little more about the above code, I check whether the character's position is less than the selection start and end to know if it's before, after, or within the selection.

I need a way to optimize this. I know it's a tough question, but I thought I'd ask anyways.

Comment: Are you *sure* you need to wrap every character in `<span>` tags?

Comment: @Blender maybe doing char by char highlighting?

Comment: @Josh: The browser handles that. Unless you mean a cursor that blinks?

Comment: @Blender I do need to wrap each char in a span tag. This is because each character may have a style associated with it. Maybe there is no way around the iteration since this is the case? I'll dig under the covers and see if I can get around the individual char wrapping...

Comment: What style do you mean? Like rich text formatting?

Comment: Exactly. I haven't gotten around to implementing the RTE styles in an optimized manner, e.g. putting a span around the entire _run_ of chars that have a specific style, and instead store the styles associated with each char in memory also. Then, when I iterate, I wrap _each_ char in a span tag and throw its style (if any) in there as well. I took this out of the code for clarity. Maybe that's the optimization I need to tackle and then I won't have to iterate like this...

Comment: It's going to be much more efficient to just insert typed characters into the appropriate existing text node rather than recreate the whole content every time. You need to try and minimize the changes you make to the DOM. You should definitely implement the optimization you mention as well.